# Does webpack's HMR work with a custom backend?

Tags: webpack, hot-module-replacement

I have an HMR problem.  I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to serve my `bundle.js`, and a separate flask backend to serve the application, which includes `bundle.js` in a `<script>`. HMR doesn't seem to work in this setup.  Is this expected?  Does HMR only work if the application itself is served by `webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: webpack-dev-server or webpack-dev-middleware.

Comment: @PlayMa256 webpack-dev-server

Comment: nono, my answer is a statement. Hot reload only works with both of them.

Comment: @PlayMa256  Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I follow.  I had it working previously when I was just using webpack-dev-server to serve both the app and the bundle.  I wasn't using webpack-dev-middleware.  I suppose I was technically by way of using webpack-dev-server, but that hasn't changed.  I'm still using webpack-dev-server to serve the bundle.  I'm just not using it to serve the app.